# what is the diference between "PlatformViewLink vs AndroidView" ? [Flutter] (Virtual Display vs Hybrid composition)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i know that whit PlatformViewLink uses a SurfaceAndroidWebView widget

i need to render in flutter a native view.
i am using this package to show a pdf https://github.com/endigo/flutter_pdfview he is using androidview but when i use setState the android view disapear, is a know issue, i am wondering if i change the widget to render the native view from Virtual Display(AndroidView) to Hybrid composition(PlatformViewLink) will help or not.
thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.